# Exchange Server 2003 not receiving email after a recovery?

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook

We have an exchange server that recently died.  I built a new server with the same operating system, reinstalled exchange 2003 with the /disasterrecovery option, installed SP2 with the disaster recovery option and then restored the exchange stores from a backup I had taken with backup exec.
When the server came online after a reboot I manually activated the stores.  Workers can send mail to the Internet but not each other.  They also cannot receive mail from the Internet. Calendar is working and Outlook clients are connecting to the server with no problem.
If I telnet to the mail server (internally) I can send a message, the server accepts it but the message never gets to the mail account.
Tech info:  Windows 2003 SP2, Exchange 2003 SP2
Please Help.

Comment: Server got same IP ? As I guess you have a redirect rule on your firewall for SMTP traffic.

Comment: Turn on the message tracking and send an email to a user from an external account. What do the logs say?

Comment: Have you consulted the logs?

Comment: Yes, everything is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be between Exchange and Outlook. Use cache mode. Maybe the mail will get to the user's online store. If possible try to recreate the profile on the local machine. This should work for most people. Copy mailbox contents using exmerg. Delete the database. Re-create the database and import the old mail back into it. Lots of help you can find here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/29umn0/deleted_all_my_outlook_pst_files_i_cant_recover/

Comment: You've been very kind in your efforts to help. Thanks for that. Solved!